# Can I run drush command from composer with custom script

Tags: 8, composer

I have a nested root Drupal 8 site.  I would like to create an import and deploy script that runs multiple drush commands.  Is this possible via custom script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this. Here is a simple example:

First, create a file called import.sh and place it in the scripts folder.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit immediately on errors, and echo commands as they are executed.
set -ex

# Run coniguration import.
cd web
echo "Running coniguration import (config split imoprt)"
drush config-split-import -y

# Clear Cache.
drush cr
```

Second update composer.json by adding the script to the scripts folder.

```
"scripts": {
  "import": [
    "./scripts/import.sh"
  ]
},
```

Now you can run `composer import`